# Get an object in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, object

I don't know if it's possible but, I've two table with a relation one-to-many `(players->statistics)`.

I get all the stats with this method :

```
return $this->db->get('statistics')->result_array();
```

Which means I also get the player_id in there, but I can get it as a string and not as an object.

What I wanted to do is this (Twig) :

`{{stat.player_id.name}}`

But that doesn't work as it's not an object.

Is it possible to do that in Codeigniter and how ?

Comment: You can used join query we will get result using Codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this :

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('statistics');
    $this->db->join('joueurs', 'joueurs.id = statistics.player_id');
    return $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it in codeIgniter
instead of `result_array()` you need to use `result()`

```
return $this->db->get('statistics')->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [joins in codeIgniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) you can achieve your desire result

Answer (score 0):

It's not working for me. I'm probably missing something.

Here's my function in Statistics_model.php :

```
function get_all_statistics()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('statistics');
    $this->db->join('joueurs', 'joueurs.id = statistics.player_id');
    return $query = $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

Index action in the controller :

```
function index()
{
    $data['statistics'] = $this->Statistic_model->get_all_statistics();

    $this->load->library('twig');
    $this->twig->display('statistics/index', $data); 

}
```

And finally the view :

```
{% for stat in statistics %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{stat.stat_id}}</td>
        <td>{{stat.leg_id}}</td>       
        <td>{{stat.player_id.name}}</td>
        <td>{{stat.darts}}</td>
        <td>{{stat.finish}}</td>
        <td>{{stat.reste}}</td>
        <td>{{stat.max}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Everything works fine but, I cannot get the player name

Comment: Does anyone have any idea ?